# You're my friend for all / whole my life

Tags: quantifiers

Which of the two quantifiers is the correct one in the following context?

> a)  You're my friend for **whole** my life.
>
> b) You're my friend for **all** my life.

The meaning is to say that this is the friend forever but using these words - plus minus.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88890/discussion-on-question-by-witty-loquacity-youre-my-friend-for-all-whole-my-li).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammar for a statement to someone about the future. A friend you have just made:

1) - **You are my friend and will be** **[for] my whole life or [for] all my life.** [notice the and]

2) - **You will be my friend [for] my whole life or [for] all my life.**

A friend you already have:

3) - You've been my friend [for] my whole life or [for] all my life. [notice the lack of **and** and that the preposition **for** calls for a present prefect. **The "for" can be implied.**

[for whole my life is not grammatical]

- for my whole life or for all my life are grammatical and invariable. **The preposition for is optional.**

There is also: lifelong friend

4) [a simple statement]: You are my friend for life [now].

That statement is future directed. It should noted that saying 4) is a performative utterance. Something happens that causes you to say that performatively.

For example, someone does you a huge favor. So, you give them a gift and say: You are my friend for life.

That implies: You are [now] my friend for life. And the reason is the favor that was done.

Answer (score 1):

OP has [remarked](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/194332/youre-my-friend-for-all-whole-my-life/194339#comment380596_194332) that the intended meaning is

> I just made a friend and I'm making a promise about the future.

So neither of the stated sentences is correct, perhaps one of these

> You will be my friend for my whole life.
>
> You will be my friend for the rest of my life.

Comment: Thank you. Is it  necessary to use the future tense here (**will**)?

Comment: in your sentence using "you're" is it unclear whether you are talking about the past or the future.

Comment: Does it mean it can be for both?

Comment: "You are my friend" is a statement about the present. If you add "for my whole life" we go right back to the question you asked.

Comment: I thought something like "You're my friend for my whole life" can have a meaning of "You're the one that I chose to be a friend for whole life".

Comment: @Wittyloquacity It's pretty clear to me that you are trying to say: You've been my friend [for] my whole life. In English for and since take the present perfect. Unless you are making a declaration: You are [now] my friend for life. I said at the beginning that I would worry about the verbs, and you said you didn't understand. Now, we are back to those verbs.

Comment: I think I'm going for your suggestion "You are my friend for life [now]" is for now and future. I wanted a short sentence like that, which implies the present and the future.

Answer (score 1):

Of the two options you've presented, I think this one sounds okay:

> You're my friend for **all my life**.

but we need to transpose two words for the second one:

> You're my friend for **my whole life**.

Idiomatically, though, I think most native speakers would simply say:

> You're a friend for life.

Here's why:

- When speaking to the friend, we can simply say "a friend" instead of "my friend". The "my" is implied, because "a friend" is taken to mean "a friend of mine" when we tell a friend, "You're a friend," as in: *You're a friend I can count on.*
- The expression "for life" is a concise, idiomatic way to say, "for my entire life", as in: *He was sentenced to prison for life*.

Comment: One and two don't work. It's because they don't work that we would say: You've been my friend for my whole life. Only the third one works in the sense of: You're a friend for life [as of this moment].

Comment: @Lambie - You seem to be assuming the OP is talking about the past. I assumed the OP is talking about the future, where "You're my friend for life" means, "You'll be my friend for life."

Comment: It's either will, or it's a declaration of the performative kind: "You are my friend for life (as you pin a medal on the person, for instance), where "now" is implied. It can't be anything else. Both you and another poster seem to think that: "You've been my friend my whole life" is about the past. That is a misunderstanding of the present perfect. That is what I am struggling to explain to both of you but to no avail.

Comment: @Lambie - "You've been my friend my whole life" certainly looks more toward the past than toward the future. (It doesn't mean the friendship is over, but it probably means the friendship didn't begin recently.) P.S. I don't think I misunderstand the present perfect, I just didn't think the OP was asking about the present perfect.

Comment: It would be extremely unusual to have a sentence in the simple present here. Except performatively. The present perfect looks to the present, is anchored in the present, but starts in the past. The OP didn't know....

Comment: @Lambie - Yes, we agree on that. There’s a lot for a learner to learn in this question. You did a good job explaining the verb tenses in your answer. I wanted to focus on the order of the wording, particularly on how it changes when we use _all_ vs. _whole_. (You touched on that in your answer, but I thought it deserved to be more front-and-center somewhere). I also wanted to highlight how we can use “for life” and forgo the usage of “all” or “whole” altogether. Anyway, I think your most recent comment (“extremely unusual”) is more on the mark than your initial “don’t work” comment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can say:

*You've been a friend for life.*

*You've been a friend my whole life.*

*You've been a friend for all my life.*

Note that you use the present perfect tense, because he was and still is a friend.

Comment: When I bid a friend farewell, is it wrong to say "You've been a friend for life."?

Comment: I am removing my comments because there is not enough room to go into this. For me, "You've been a friend for life" sounds as if that friendship is coming to an end....